# Pivot using Max in Azure DW(Synapse)

Tags: azure, t-sql, pivot, azure-synapse

I am facing a strange issue with pivot in azure sql dw. I have 2 rows in staging table as below

```
Select Flag, Number,Value,Interest from stg.tableA where Number = 400799074  

Flag        Number       Value    Interest
Federal     0400799074  12540.8    0
Provincial  0400799074  248.97    -0.01
```

The query to pivot and populate my destination table is below

```
SELECT
Number
,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Value], 0) ELSE 0  END) AS  [FederalValue]
,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Value], 0) ELSE 0  END) AS [ProvincialValue]
,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal'  THEN ISNULL(stg.[Interest], 0) ELSE 0  END) AS [FederalInterest]
,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Interest], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [ProvincialInterest]
FROM
[stg].[TableA]   stg
where LoanNumber = 400799074  
GROUP BY 
stg.Number
```

The output I get is

```
Number      FederalValue    ProvincialValue   FederalIntrest    ProvincialInterest 
400799074    12540.8         248.97             0                   0
```

I am missing something as I dont understand why is ProvincialInterest 0 and not -0.01

The datatype in stg table is float and destination table is decimal(15,2).

When I remove the else condition I get the correct result, I cannot remove them becasue there will be scenarios where "provincial" row will not exist.

```
,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Interest], 0) /*ELSE 0  removed */ END) AS [ProvincialInterest]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick sample data**

```
declare @tableA table
(
    Flag nvarchar(20),
    Number nvarchar(20),
    Value money,
    Interest money
);

insert into @tableA (Flag, Number, Value, Interest) values
('Federal', '0400799074', 12540.80, 0.0),
('Provincial', '0400799074', 248.97, -0.01),
('Federal', '0423456789', 123.45,  10.0); --Number without Provincial level
```

**Quick and dirty solution**

When fetching a maximum value over a data set that contains negative values, then you should not replace unknown (`null`) values with 0 (the `ISNULL(..., 0)` part). Instead you should use the minimum value for that data type. Here I just used `-99999` to prove the 'large negative value' point.

```
select  Number
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal'    THEN ISNULL(stg.[Value],    0) ELSE -99999 END) AS [FederalValue]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Value],    0) ELSE -99999 END) AS [ProvincialValue]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal'    THEN ISNULL(stg.[Interest], 0) ELSE -99999 END) AS [FederalInterest]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN ISNULL(stg.[Interest], 0) ELSE -99999 END) AS [ProvincialInterest]
FROM @tableA stg
group by stg.Number;
```

This query has a result with the required `-0.01`, but also contains the replacement value `-99999.00` that must still be handled to get the requested result.

**The better solution**

Determining a suitable negative replacement value (such as `-99999`) might be hard if you do not know the full range of your data values. Therefore I would suggest to let the `MAX()` function handle the unknowns (`NULL`). Hint: the function ignores them... Replace any `NULL` values as a final step. This means moving the `ISNULL()` function outside the `MAX()` function.

```
select  Number
        ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal'    THEN stg.[Value]    END), 0) AS [FederalValue]
        ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN stg.[Value]    END), 0) AS [ProvincialValue]
        ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Federal'    THEN stg.[Interest] END), 0) AS [FederalInterest]
        ,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'Provincial' THEN stg.[Interest] END), 0) AS [ProvincialInterest]
from @tableA stg
group by stg.Number;
```

**Sample result**

The result from the *better* solution.

```
Number               FederalValue          ProvincialValue       FederalInterest       ProvincialInterest
-------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
0400799074           12540,80              248,97                0,00                  -0,01
0423456789           123,45                0,00                  10,00                 0,00
```

Comment: 'The better solution' works, but the 'Quick and Dirty Solution' still does show the 'ProvincialIntrest' as 0 and not -0.01

Comment: @sab You are correct, I revised my answer to reflect this! Only the 'better solution' immediately produces the required result.